# Way to automatically clear all applications connected to the queue

Tags: ibm-mq

We have an environment where MQ acts as an interface between
Websites and Micro Focus. Sometimes a message gets stuck in a queue,
thereby blocking all the communications over that particular queue. If
the queue depth increases greatly, all the communication stops in the
queue manager.

When we check the status of queue, we see that microfocus process is present there.

Is there are way to automatically clear all applications connected to the queue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to close an applications handle on a given queue but you could have a script that runs a couple of MQSC commands against the queue manager to first get the connection identifier using the [DISPLAY CONN](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc11950_.htm) command and then close the connection using the [STOP CONN](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc13370_.htm) command. You could then setup a trigger on the queue that executes the script once a certain queue depth has been reached.